# How to use Django Proxy Model given a django model object or queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 questions regarding proxy from model,

1. How to create a proxy object from model object?
2. How to create a proxy QuerySet from model QuerySet?

For example, assume we have defined:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyProxyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def say_hello(self):
        return "Hello, {}".format(self.get_full_name())
```

One way to convert successfully is by re-querying the object, which is unnecessary.

```
# Retrieve from model Object.
# Assume: request is HttpRequest from authenticated user.
my_user = MyProxyUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk) # Hit Database
my_user.say_hello()


# Retrieve from model QuerySet.
# Assume: users = User.objects.all()
MyProxyUser.objects.filter(pk__in=users)
```

Comment: One area to think of solving this issue perhaps is by object copy, but I'm not too sure on the approach.

Comment: I randomly tried `MyProxyUser(request.user)` for a luck expecting it to make the proxy object, but it doesn't work because proxy is not initialize that way.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to assign the model attribute of your queryset

```py
users = User.objects.all()
users.model = MyProxyUser
users.first().say_hello()
```

*Edit*: For assigning proxy class to a django model object, try

```py
    user = User.objects.all()
    user.__class__ = MyProxyUser
```

Comment: Better than so many other answers I found, and honestly surprising that it works this easily.

Comment: But how do we do that for objects.

Comment: user.__class__ = MyProxyUser

Comment: user = User.objects.get(pk=1);      user.__class__ = MyProxyUser

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Ramast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39138828/705296), you can also build a function on your proxy model class to consistently do this for you:

```py
class MyProxyUser(User):
...
    @staticmethod
    def from_user(user: UserManager):
        """ Get a PAUser classed instance from a User object.

        Useful for Signals and other Django defaults that send base User objects.
        """
        user.model = PAUser
        return user
...
```